# Angular 2: http.get don't understand ts extension

Tags: http, angular

Angular Cli project, in **root folder** I have a  file **lessons.ts** ( to store data)  and in **app folder**, i have **lesson.service.ts**  (to retrieve data), code look like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs';

//import Lesson
import { Lesson } from './lesson.class';

@Injectable()
export class LessonService {

    lessons=[];

    constructor(private http: Http) { 
        this.loadLessons();
    }

    loadLessons(){
        this.http.get('./lessons')
                .map(res=>res.json())
                .subscribe(
                    lessons=>this.lessons =lessons,
                    err => console.log(err)
                )
    }
}
```

Console threw out a error message:

```
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:4200/lessons 404 (Not Found)
```

to fix it, i  modified **lessons.service.ts**

```
.....
this.http.get('./lessons.ts')  ->I added '.ts' for lessons file
...
```

But the browser keep throwing bug:

```
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:4200/lessons.ts 404 (Not Found)
```

Has anyone ever encountered this bug? 
Any idea would be appreciated !

Comment: what is `./lessons`?

Comment: './lessons' is the  url  to file lessons.ts I put in the root folder

Comment: Why are you using HTTP to access it if it's elsewhere in your own application? I'd recommend you read e.g. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html to understand how services are supposed to work. There is actually an example there using static data in a TS file.

Comment: Also note that `'./lessons'` is **not a URL**, it's a *relative path* to that file (and probably not the right one, unless that file is actually in the same folder as the service).

Comment: take a look at this example of `http.get` reading a `config.json` https://plnkr.co/edit/60E2qb9gOjvkEAeR5CtE?p=preview

Comment: What's the code in lessons.ts?

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of problems. First of all, if it would work, (it wouldn't any how), your path is wrong in http call, since you said that the lessons.ts is in the root folder.

And as commented above, why http if you have static data?? Here could be one solution...

Don't know how your Lesson actually looks like... this could be it:

```
export class Lesson {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

then your lessons.ts file could look like this... put it in the app folder.

```
import { Lesson } from './lesson.class';

export const LESSONS: Lesson[] = 
    {id: 1, name: 'lesson1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'lesson2'}
];
```

lesson.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

//import Lesson
import { Lesson } from './lesson.class';
import { LESSONS } from './lessons';

@Injectable()
export class LessonService {

    loadLessons(){
        return LESSONS;
    }
}
```

And the component where you display out lessons:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Lesson } from './lesson.class';
import { LessonService } from './lesson.service';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private lessonService: LessonService) {  }

    lessons: Lesson[];

    ngOnInit {
        this.lessons = this.lessonService.loadLessons();
    }
}
```

As also commented, check out services: [Tour of heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)

Comment: Or `return Observable.of(LESSONS)`, and update the component accordingly, to keep a consistent interface if the long-term aim is to switch it out for an actual API.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer would be,

```
http.get('here make sure you have a valid url/path which points to 
          Webapi/Webservice/jsonfile etc..., which can actually return data')....
```

In your case it is none of them that's why you are getting an error.